# Why is this boolean casting not working as expected?

Tags: javascript, casting, boolean

I've just answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17590180/561309) but I don't understand why it works the way it does.

Basically the problem can be simplified to this:

```
var b = new Boolean(false);
console.info(b == false); // Prints "true" - OK
console.info(b && true); // Prints "true" - but should be "false"
```

I assume there's some unintuitive automatic casting going on but I don't understand it would sometime be automatically casted to `true`, sometime to `false`. Any idea?

I guess this illustrates the problem better:

```
> false && 123

false // OK 

> new Boolean(false) && 123

123   // ???
```

Comment: how are you saying `b && false` shold be true

Comment: Interesting question! Added a clarifying example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe the object b is true when doing (b && false) but doing to logical operation of true and false results to false.

If you do this:

```
var b = new Boolean(false);
console.info(b == false); // Prints "true" - OK
console.info(b && true); // Prints "true"
```

So even though the object b was set to false in the (b && true) it results to true because it exists and it's not set to null.

Answer (score 2):

`==` does a lot of coercion:

```
Object == false =>
Object == 0 =>
Object.valueOf() == 0 =>
false == 0 =>
0 == 0 =>
true
```

Or if you follow the [steps in the algorithm](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3), it is

```
Step 7, Step 9, Step 6, Step 1 c iii.
```

The [logical and just goes directly for `ToBoolean`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.11), which [always returns `true` for objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-9.2).

Note that [`new Boolean` returns an object and not a boolean value.](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.6.2.1)

Comment: In other words, `Boolean(new Boolean(false))` is true. Javascript in its element!

Comment: These wrapper objects are completely useless anyway now that `this` can be a primitive in ES 5.1

Answer (score 0):

False AND False is false. Truth tables - AND only returns true if both arguments are true, <del>and neither is in this case</del>.

EDIT: True AND False is also false, so anything && False is false.

Comment: but he is doing `True AND False`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly but it look like the major issue derives from the fact that `if (new Boolean(false))` evaluates to true. If you put expressions in an `if` statement or link them with logical operators (i.e. `&&`), JavaScript only checks if they are **truthy** or **falsy**. When it comes to boolean primitives, it is easy:

```
true -> truthy
false -> falsy
```

But when it comes to boolean objects, it looks different:

```
new Boolean(false) -> truthy
new Boolean(true) -> truthy
```

The reason for this is, that in JavaScript, every object (if not null) is truthy.